# string parsing in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a string like this:

```
S(08-01-2008) I[18] ф4(579.1900 UAH) E(05-07-2009)R[5](117.1900) V[0](0.0000) Up(22-04-2009)
```

I need get **Up** value: **22-04-2009**

Comment: So what is your question? What have you tried? What's wrong at all ?

Comment: @Teneff the problem is I can do that on C#, but I don't know javascript

Comment: @Wachburn You don't get the point! Your question is unclear!

Comment: @Wachburn : I don't see how he could be more clear.

Comment: Show us what (pseudo) C# code would solve your problem - we don't know about your string format and can only guess

Comment: @Bergi KooiInc knows my string format, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
'S(08-01-2008) I[18] ф4(579.1900 UAH) E(05-07-2009) R5 V0 Up(22-04-2009)'
 .match(/Up\(.+\)/g);
```

It returns an array of matched values, here `["Up(22-04-2009)"]`

Value only could be:

```
'S(08-01-2008) I[18] ф4(579.1900 UAH) E(05-07-2009) R5 V0 Up(22-04-2009)'
 .match(/Up\(.+\)/g)[0].split(/\(|\)/)[1];
```

Or

```
'S(08-01-2008) I[18] ф4(579.1900 UAH) E(05-07-2009) R5 V0 Up(22-04-2009)'
 .match(/Up\(.+\)/g)[0].replace(/Up\(|\)/g,'');
```

If you're not sure 'Up(...)' exists in the string:

```
( 'S(08-01-2008) I[18] ф4(579.1900 UAH) E(05-07-2009) R5 V0 Up(22-04-2009)'
   .match(/Up\(.+\)/g) || ['not found'][0] ) 
 .replace(/Up\(|\)/g,'');
```

Comment: how can i get value between brackets?

Answer (score 1):

```
extract = yourString.substr( -11,10);
```

It will extract 10 chars starting by the 11th counting from end.

This assume that the up value is always at the end of your input string.

This one is much faster than regex, or split solutions if you just need one value.

More example at :
http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2159-Using-Slice-Substring-And-Substr-In-Javascript.htm

Answer (score 1):

You can easily [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) a regular expression or get some [`substring`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) from a certain (or computed) position, but let's try to *parse* it with a regex and [`split`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
var str = "S(08-01-2008) I[18] ф4(579.1900 UAH) E(05-07-2009)R[5](117.1900) V[0](0.0000) Up(22-04-2009)";

var parts = str.split(/\s*\(\s*(.+?)\s*\)\s*/);
var map = {};
for (var i=0; i+1<parts.length; i+=2)
    map[parts[i]] = parts[i+1];
```

Now, you can get the "Up" value from the map via

```
return map["Up"]; // "22-04-2009"
```

In contrast to the other answers, this will result in `undefined` if there is no "Up" value in the string instead of throwing an exception. Also, you can get the other values from the map if you need them, for example `map["I[18] ф4"]` is `"I[18] ф4"`.